# Select top row based on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I think it is a common situation, but I am not able to get the logic.
I have a table as follows.

```
PersonID SchoolID EndDate
-------- -------- -------
1        ABC      2013
1        DEF      2014
1        GHI      2010
2        XYZ      2013    
2        UVW      2011
```

I want the following output

```
PersonID SchoolID EndDate
-------- -------- -------
1        DEF      2014
2        XYZ      2013
```

Basically, I want the latest school for each person. Hence, I try to do something like

```
SELECT SchoolID, PersonID,EndDate FROM tbl
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING EndDate = MAX(ENDDATE)
ORDER BY EndDate DESC
```

But I got an error saying EndDate is invalid in a HAVING clause because it is not contained in an aggregate function or group by clause.
I tried doing this

```
SELECT SchoolID, PersonID,MAX(EndDate) FROM tbl
GROUP BY PersonID
ORDER BY EndDate DESC
```

I get an error saying SchoolID is invalid in the select list because of the same reason.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID 
                                  ORDER BY EndDate DESC)  AS RN
        FROM Table1)
select PersonId, SchoolId, EndDate from cte
where RN = 1
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43003/4)

Comment: Thanks. I think this should work. It seems complicated though for a simple requirement. I believe the CTE is only used to eliminate RN from the select list, right?

Comment: @Torpedo No, it's just here to be able to use ROW_NUMBER value in a where clause. It could be replaced by a subquery only. Cause you can't use a "window function" directly in a where clause.

Comment: Oh ok. So ROW_NUMBER would not be available in a subquery, it has to be used in a CTE.

Comment: @Torpedo in a subquery yes. But not directly in a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap `MAX(Date)` in a subquery.

```
SELECT SchoolID, PersonID, Date
FROM table1 t
WHERE Date =
    (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM table1
    WHERE PersonID = t.PersonID);
```

Note: this will give multiple rows for one PersonID if there are multiple dates tied for the max.

Comment: Almost helps me. But if I just need the top row or the first row for the group, is there anything that can be done other than @Raphael's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
      with temp as
      (
       SELECT PersonID,MAX(EndDate) as enddate FROM TABLE
       GROUP BY PersonID
      )
       select TABLE.* from TABLE inner join  temp on TABLE.personid=temp.personid
and  TABLE.enddate=temp.enddate;
```

Comment: If you get a chance, please add some comments for the OP on what this code does.

Comment: I believe the result is similar to the solution by @popovitsj. But if there are same end dates for the same person, I will get multiple rows, which I dont want to have.